# SVG / PDF image without interpolation?

Tags: inkscape, pdf, interpolation

I exported an heatmap from Matlab as PDF. If I view the PDF created by matlab `print -painters -dpdf` command, I see the correct output:

[image]

However if I import into Inkscape (either via Poppler or not) with the image gets interpolated and blurred:

[image]

When I re-save as pdf, it also looks interpolated. I have noted the svg xml code for the image is like this:

```
  <image
     y="172.88283"
     x="136.01956"
     id="image2718"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAOCAYAAAAfSC3RAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAPZJREFUKJGNkTFuwzAMRZ889SaVoct08G1qIwN9lAwdPPQuhSEfJUOA34GyJScB2g8QEiT+z08SMJGkeubnO9nD5EEWOynr3R+yavIu2JAvUO4HyZoK1ih7JP0cYqZPBZLEuuFYgMHPNPrTOlNR/oCOdYMczyTqcSZB0gfYSHBrf2EAizDNmG5M20y1ahG+SqV+PvPSiLezu9qtpgjT1jo6Y30QYmmtNv39A93rEkOdagsbyboCEMoySbqzhm/qINoVNYI5wgABk2oSL5K9kucsh0AHcKH3AbGQdMd0Kz17G3mMZddV+LBqujKFN1cfgL6twMNK4Bdchqf6VbHBwQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     height="198.95876"
     width="185.10374" />
```

When I export to PDF from Inkscape, it also looks similarly blurred.
Any idea how to make it look like the original PDF above, after editing in inkscape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the *Bitmap scale (image rendering)* in the preferences to *Blocky(optimizeSpeed)*

[image]

[Here's an example SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/7iZ.svg)

Comment: It's also possible to do this per image. Right-click on image, select 'Object Properties', and select the 'Optimize Speed' option in the 'Image rendering' dropdown.

In addition to this, the pdf renderer needs to support this rendering mode. A trick would be to make a bitmap copy of the enlarged, blocky picture (Edit > Make Bitmap Copy). The dpi value for this can be set in the preferences at Edit > Preferences > Bitmaps > Create. Make it large :)

Comment: Great, confirmed both this and @Moini's method seem to work both in inkscape and saving as pdf. Thanks!